# How to set multiple connection of job queue?

Tags: laravel, queue

My enviroment is
PHP7.0
Laravel 5.4

I want to achieve multiple connection on job queue,following is my codes:

```
$delay = Carbon::parse($memberCoupon->started_at)->diffInSeconds(Carbon::now());
$job = (new GrantCoupon($memberCoupon, $delay))
          ->onConnection('redis')->onQueue('coupons');
$this->dispatch($job);
```

and my `.env`

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

my `queue.php`

```
'redis' => [
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'connection' => 'default',
    'queue' => '{default}',
    'retry_after' => 90,
]
```

if I use the method above `onConnection('redis')->onQueue('coupons')`, I will immeidately receive a message(the class `GrantCoupon` ),but the `delay` will not work.
I kown I have set the `QUEUE_DRIVER` to `sync`, I just want to achieve to custom connection by onConnect, but the result is that it does not work, How can I make it work?

Comment: I do not understand your question, could you please clarify? What's the objective and what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: your question is damn confusing, dont change any connection in run time you will most proppably lose the queue length.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English.    In my website, there is a coupon delivery activity.   Now I create a new activity. If the start time is greater than the present time, the card will be issued automatically at the start time
Now I want to implement the specific connection to the queue, and in the case where my default queue driver is sync, I want to use the redis driver to perform the above task.  So I used `onConnection` and `onQueue`, but so far, it hasn't woked yet

Comment: I eventually know what I want to express. I want to have multiple queue driver to different jobs. For example, in `.env`, I set `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync`, but in another job, I want to use `redis`. but the above I have used did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$delay = Carbon::parse($memberCoupon->started_at)->diffInSeconds(Carbon::now());
$job = new GrantCoupon($memberCoupon);
$this->dispatch($job)->delay($delay)->onConnection('redis')->onQueue('coupons');
```

Your queue job will come into effect when dispatching, including the delay.